# Opencv copy 3 channel IplImage to 4 channel IplImage

Tags: c++, opencv, iplimage

When I try to use cvCopy a IplImage consisting of 3 channels to a IplImage with 4 channels (I need the extra channel later) all I get is an error message.

Is there another way to increase the channel count of an IplImage without loosing the data that it already holds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [cvMixChannels](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=mix#cvMixChannels), like this:

```
CvMat * src; // your source image
CvMat * dst // your destination image
CvMat * zeros = cvCreateMat(src->cols, src->rows, CV_8UC1);
cvSet(zeros, cvScalar(0, 0, 0, 0));
CvArr * input[] = { src, zeros };
int from_to[] = { 0,0, 1,1, 2,2, 3,3 };
cvMixChannels(input, 2, &dst, 1, from_to, 4);
```

It will perform only the copy operations that are neccessary, unlike cvSplit and cvMerge.

Comment: "The function cvMixChannels is a generalized form of cvSplit and cvMerge and some forms of cvCvtColor." - so says The Holy OpenCV Documentation. So you could simply use cvSplit and cvMerge to do the same.

Comment: If you look at the source code, you'll see that actually cvSplit and cvMerge are special cases of cvMixChannels. Therefore, cvSplit-ing an image and the cvMerge-ing the channels again is not the same as single cvMixChannels call. (Although cvSplit and cvMerge do not call cvMixChannels, their code is basically the same, but with the fromTo values hardcoded.)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, the way i'm gonna suggest is the easiest one :

1. You can first split your image with cvSplit() into 3 separate images
   (one for each channel)
2. Then you recompose a 4 channels one with 3 channels + the one you
   will add using the function cvMerge()....

Look at the documentation here,

- [Doc here ==> cvSplit()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvsplit#cvSplit)
- [Doc here ==> cvMerge()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvmerge#cvMerge)

Julien,