# JavaCV convert 3 channel IplImage to 4 channel Iplmage

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I have tried some methods to create a new 4 channel IplImage from a 3 channel IplImage.I have tried to convert this code from C to JavaCV:

```
CvMat * src; // your source image
CvMat * dst // your destination image
CvMat * zeros = cvCreateMat(src->cols, src->rows, CV_8UC1);
cvSet(zeros, cvScalar(0, 0, 0, 0));
CvArr * input[] = { src, zeros };
int from_to[] = { 0,0, 1,1, 2,2, 3,3 };
cvMixChannels(input, 2, &dst, 1, from_to, 4);
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871978/opencv-copy-3-channel-iplimage-to-4-channel-iplimage),my conversion is:

```
    CvMat src; 
    CvMat dst;
    CvMat zeros = cvCreateMat(src.cols(), src.rows(), CV_8UC1);
    cvSet(zeros, cvScalar(0, 0, 0, 0));
    CvArr input[] = { src, zeros };
    int from_to[] = { 0,0, 1,1, 2,2, 3,3 };
    cvMixChannels(input, 2, dst, 1, from_to, 4);
```

But eclipse says,that the JavaCV mix channels method is this:

> ```
> The method cvMixChannels(opencv_core.CvArr[], int, opencv_core.CvArr[], int, int[],int) in the type opencv_core is not applicable for the arguments opencv_core.CvArr[], int, opencv_core.CvMat, int, int[], int)
> ```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: no idea about javacv, but there should be an equivalent to cvtColor(src,dst,CV_BGR2BGRA) there as well.

Comment: I have tried it,but the image shown as if it has a red filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you pass `CvMat` as first and third arguments to `cvMixChannels`, while you are expected to pass `CvMat[]`.